# Testing scenarios for a desktop personal cloud app

Tags: manual-testing

What are some high level test scenarios/types of testing for a personal cloud desktop application? This is basically a Network Attached Storage that can be accessed from anywhere via a desktop, mobile or web application, and my focus will be desktop application.

I started with the following scenarios:
- install/uninstall
- login/logout
- Add, read, modify, delete data using Wifi and Wired connections

Answer (score 3):

***You could test file transfers:***

- transfer file
- transfer multiple files
- cancel in the middle of file tranfer
- transfer other media types - test outside of "supported" range, videos, pdf, gif, etc.

Comment: I tested file transfer with common file types. I will make a collection of all file types(common or not) and make sure to use them all. Thanks

Comment: Wonderful news!

Answer (score 1):

- Stress testing, do you have in mind how many users are accessing your application at peak time?
- soak testing, you need to know how reliable your application is, having your application running for a long time and see how often it fails. This is very hard to test as you can not use any simulation to shorten the testing time.
- Security testing, does your application prevent unauthorized users.
- Password recovery, if a user forgets password, how easy is it to recover it?

Comment: **Stress testing** - this is on my to-do list
**Soak testing** - good idea. I will write some automated tests that creates/modifies/deletes/moves files just like a regular user, and run them overnight.
**Security testing** - I plan on learning more on this field, but it's very complex and I need good research
**Password recovery** - already covered this scenario. 
Thanks for the input